# Parsing semi colon delimeter file

Tags: c#, regex, csv, textfieldparser

I have a CSV file but the delimiter is a semi colon `;` and each column is enclosed with double quotes. There are also occurrences of `;` in some values such as `& amp;`

I am using *TextFieldParser* to parse the file. This is the sample data:

> `"A001";"RT:This is a tweet"; "http://www.whatever.com/test/module & amp;one"`

For the above example , I am getting more columns/fields than what I should get.

> `Field[0] = "A001"`
>   `Field[1] = "RT:This is a tweet"`
>   `Field[2] = "http://www.whatever.com/test/module&amp"`
>   `Field[3] = "one"`

This is my code. What changes need to be done to handle such scenario?

```
 using (var parser  =  new TextFieldParser(fileName))
            {
                parser.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;
                parser.SetDelimiters(";");
                parser.TrimWhiteSpace = true;
                parser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = false;

                int rowIndex = 0;
                PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(TwitterData).GetProperties();
                while (parser.PeekChars(1) != null)
                {
                    var cleanFieldRowCells = parser.ReadFields().Select(
                        f => f.Trim(new[] { ' ', '"' }));

                    var twitter = new TwitterData();
                    int index = 0;
                    foreach (string c in cleanFieldRowCells)
                    {
                            string str = c;

                            if (properties[index].PropertyType == typeof(DateTime))
                            {
                                string twitterDateTemplate = "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss +ffff yyyy";
                                DateTime createdAt = DateTime.ParseExact(str, twitterDateTemplate, new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-AU"));
                                properties[index].SetValue(twitter, createdAt);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                properties[index].SetValue(twitter, str);
                            }

                        index++;
                    }
                }
```

-Alan-

Comment: Did you try setting `HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes` to true?

Comment: Yes I did but no different

Comment: Try calling System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode() on each line. It will turn `&amp;` into '&', as well as decoding anything else.

Comment: I do have a scenario where the data looks like "A001";"RT: Test1 ; Test2";"http://www.test.com". Does the above also handle "Test1;Test2"?

Comment: `System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode()` only decodes **`HTML`**. I.e. `&amp;`, `&gt;`, etc. It won't affect anything else, so something like `"A001";"RT: Test1 ; Test2";"test.com";` will be ignored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the two sample strings you have above and setting the `HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes` property to true works for me.

```
string LINES = @"
    ""A001"";""RT:This is a tweet""; ""http://www.whatever.com/test/module&amp;one""
    ""A001"";""RT: Test1 ; Test2"";""test.com"";   
";
using (var sr = new StringReader(LINES))
{
    using (var parser = new TextFieldParser(sr))
    {
        parser.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;
        parser.SetDelimiters(";");
        parser.TrimWhiteSpace = true;
        parser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;

        while (parser.PeekChars(1) != null)
        {
            var cleanFieldRowCells = parser.ReadFields().Select(
                f => f.Trim(new[] { ' ', '"' })).ToArray();
            Console.WriteLine("New Line");
            for (int i = 0; i < cleanFieldRowCells.Length; ++i)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(
                    "Field[{0}] = [{1}]", i, cleanFieldRowCells[i]
                );
            }
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", new string('=', 40));
        }
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
New Line
Field[0] = [A001]
Field[1] = [RT:This is a tweet]
Field[2] = [http://www.whatever.com/test/module&amp;one]
========================================
New Line
Field[0] = [A001]
Field[1] = [RT: Test1 ; Test2]
Field[2] = [test.com]
Field[3] = []
========================================
```

Comment: the above working fine as it is. However if I copy the LINES to a file and read the contents from the file (File.ReadAllText), I am getting exception (" Line 1 cannot be parsed using the current Delimiters ")

Comment: @AlanB - you can't just copy `LINES` as-is, because it's a **`C# verbatim string`**. I.e. the double quotes are escaped. Instead, the text file [should look like this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kuujinbo/StackOverflow.RegularExpressions/master/_INPUT/TextFieldParseRegex.txt), and you can then pass the path to the text file as you did in your original example, instead of using `File.ReadAllText()`. [Take a look at the update](https://github.com/kuujinbo/StackOverflow.RegularExpressions/blob/master/CSharp/TextFieldParseRegex.cs).